# handling ampersand (&) in input using js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This has been asked before but mine is different. I cant rub my head around this. I have a wysiwyg form that is being fetched by jquery and saved by ajax

```
var content=$('.inputfield').val();

fields='front='+fcarddetails;
 $.ajax({
  method:'POST',
  url:actionpage,
  data:fields,
   beforeSend:function()
   {
 $("#processing").show();
   },

  complete:function ()
   {
  $("#processing").hide();  
   },
  success: function(feedback)
    {
    }    etc.
```

When '&' is added to the field, the whole input is messed up. 
I a have handled all the html escapes, filters and special characters. But the code gets broken even before it reaches php action page. I cant convert '&' to & because it still contains '&'. Please help, problem is in js, not php but you can prove me otherwise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: URL encode it.  `&` is a key symbol in query strings for separating data.

Comment: *"This has been asked before but mine is different."* Almost certainly not. In any case, link to the previous questions you've read, and say **how** you think yours is different.

Comment: &T.J. Crowder,  its duplicatate no doubt. My bad, I didn't know its an ajax issue so I was searching wrongly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the string using [**encodeURIComponent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

> The **encodeURIComponent()** method encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

```js
var fcarddetails = 'Tom&Jerry';

fields = 'front=' + encodeURIComponent(fcarddetails);

document.write(fields);
```